# How do I sort an array of objects based on a number property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I have an array like the one in the code below, and I would want to sort it on height. So that the shortest person will log when I do console.log(array[0]);

I have no idea how to do so

```
let array = [
    {
        name: "John",
        gender: "male",
        height_meters: 1.8
    },
    {
        name: "Cathrine",
        gender: "female",
        height_meters: 1.7
    }
]
```

Comment: If you read [the documentation on array sorting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you'll see explanations and examples.

Comment: `array.sort(person => person.height_meters)`. The argument to the sort method lets you specify how elements should be compared (identity by default)

Comment: @wbadart, that is not right. you need both arguments and the delta of the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native way

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.height_meters - b.height_meters);
```

With Lodash library

```
_.orderBy(arr, ['height_meters'], ['asc']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this works, I'll vote it for correct answer in a bit thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We seperate out the sort here, it allows us to have clarity to our code, but also makes it easy to swap out or re-use.
Sort is looking for us to return one of three values in order for it to sort elements. `Less than zero` `0` and `Greater than zero`. Most documentation will show this as a rigid `-1`, `0`, `1`. But any positive and negative can be substituted for the `-1` and `+1` which gives us the ability to be so concise when sorting numbers.

```js
let array = [
    {
        name: "John",
        gender: "male",
        height_meters: 1.8
    },
    {
        name: "Cathrine",
        gender: "female",
        height_meters: 1.7
    },
    {
        name: "Cathrine",
        gender: "female",
        height_meters: 1.3
    },
    {
        name: "Cathrine",
        gender: "female",
        height_meters: 1.95
    },
    {
        name: "Cathrine",
        gender: "female",
        height_meters: 2.7
    }
]

const sortBy = (itemA, itemB) => itemA.height_meters - itemB.height_meters;

console.log(array.sort(sortBy));
```

Comment: Although this is correct, you should add some explanation as to why this works.

Comment: Thats a fair comment @nem035

Comment: thanks man! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.sort()`:

```
array.sort((a,b)=>{
    return a.height_meters-b.height_meters
})
```

I hope this will help!